# Checking for prime number - C# logic

Tags: c#, primes

Here is a snippet from my code. Basically once the button is clicked this logic should fire out and determine if the number is prime or not. The problem is that some numbers are returning as "not prime", when in reality they are. Can anyone point out where the flaw is?

Thank you

```
    private void bntTestPrime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num;
        double num_sqrt;
        int num_fl;

        num = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);

        num_sqrt = Math.Sqrt(num);

        num_fl = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(num_sqrt));

        for (int i = 1; i <= num_fl; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0 && i != num)
                lblResult_prime.Text = "Number " + num + " is not Prime.";
            else
                lblResult_prime.Text = "Number " + num + " is Prime.";
        }

    }
```

Comment: What numbers are prime, but are listed as not prime? What prime and composite numbers work? What have you tried already?

Comment: Basically the very first numbers, such as 2 and 3. I do realize what the logic should be and what principal should be used to find the prime numbers, though my programming skills didn't let me write intelligent code enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to [*Blender*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17895057/1715579), I'd like to point out that you're simply setting the output text on every iteration loop. That means your result will only depend upon the last number checked. What you need to do is assume the number is prime and loop through until a divisor is found. If a divisor is found. The number is prime if and only if no divisors are found. In the end the code should look something like this:

```
private bool IsPrime(int num)
{
    double num_sqrt = Math.Sqrt(num);
    int num_fl = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(num_sqrt));

    for (int i = 2; i <= num_fl; i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
       }
    }
    return true;
}

private void bntTestPrime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int num = Convert.ToInt32(txtInput.Text);
    bool isPrime = IsPrime(num);
    if (isPrime)
        lblResult_prime.Text = "Number " + num + " is Prime.";
    else
        lblResult_prime.Text = "Number " + num + " is not Prime.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This worked like a charm!
I've been researching the question and avoiding the use of bool to be able to get as simple of a code as possible. But looks like I should have used bool method to be begin with.

Answer (score 1):

1 is a factor of every number, so you shouldn't check it. Start at 2. Also, you're already looping from 2 to `sqrt(num)`, so there's no way for `i` to be equal to `num`.

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease the performance hit on checking large numbers by using a conditional to check the first 4 primes, then start the loop at 11 and increment by 2.  Something like this:

```
    private bool IsPrime(int num)
    {
        double num_sqrt = Math.Sqrt(num);
        int num_fl = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(num_sqrt));
        if (num !=1 && num !=2 && num != 3 && num != 5 && num != 7 && num % 2 > 0 _
            && num % 3 > 0 && num % 5 > 0 && num % 7 > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 11; i <= num_fl; i+=2)
            {
                if (num % i == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

You can shorten your code and increase the performance tremendously by using a List of primes that go big enough to cover the upper limit you want to check.  Then use the Contains method to test for prime.

Comment: In tests that I've done I found a significant time saving.  I think the conditional uses less overhead than the loop.  Also if you examine it you'll see that a very high percentage probably 80-90 percent of composite numbers are multiples of the first 4 primes.

Comment: If you want something fast, don't use the naive algorithm. Optimizing it won't make it fast.

Comment: I didn't say it was fast just faster.  If you read the whole answer, I provided a much faster method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below.

```
bool IsPrime(int number) {

   if(number%2==0 && number!=2) return false; //no need to check for even numbers
   for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {


     if (number % i == 0 && i != number) return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
bool isPrimeNubmer(int n)
    {
        if (n >=0 && n < 4) //1, 2, 3 are prime numbers
            return true;
        else if (n % 2 == 0) //even numbers are not prime numbers
            return false;
        else
        {
            int j = 3;
            int k = (n + 1) / 2 ;

            while (j <= k)
            {
                if (n % j == 0)
                    return false;
                j = j + 2;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PrimeChecker
{
    public static bool Prime(int m) 
{ 
    for (int i =2; i< m; i++)
        {
        if (m % i ==0)
            {
             return false ;
            }
        }
return true; 
    }
public static void Main()
{
        Console.WriteLine(Prime(13));

    }
}
```